# stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString() for Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm having a problem when using `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString()` into the latest version of Xcode 8.2 Beta. When using the function, Xcode is showing that the value type of string has no member.

```
var clockworkSmsUrl = "https://api.clockworksms.com/http/send.aspx?"
                       + "key=123456789abcd"
                       + "to="
                       + usersNumber!
                       + "&content="
                       + usersTextMessage!

clockworkSmsUrl.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "+")
var clockworkSmsURLconvert = NSURL(string: clockworkSmsUrl)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that there is "Edit -> Convert To -> Latest Swift Syntax", did you try that? – Btw, your code discards the result of the conversion, is that your real code?

Comment: Everything you need to learn about the changes is here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md

Comment: @MartinR , "Edit -> Convert To -> Latest Swift Syntax" is not working for all, In my case I have to resolve around more than 400 errors related to conversion on my own.

Comment: @infiniteLoop: Not in all cases, but it does fix *this* issue automatically.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can fix your snippet using ...

```
clockworkSmsUrl.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
```

Swift 3 changed the way how objc APIs are imported.

Please note that there are some issues with the code you posted:

- the result of `replacingOccurrences` is discarded.
- there are more characters to be escaped.
- `URLCompontents` exposes safer ways to construct URLs.